# type mismatch error on loop in vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm working in Outlook VBA and have constructed a For Next loop to read in the body of MailItems which are formatted like Key=Value pairs.  To a point it seems to be working, but on the end of the second iteration when it reaches the "Next oitem" I get the error thrown "type mismatch".  Well,there is still a third MailItem to be read in, so I don't know why I am getting this error.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Sub ReadMailItems()

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olappns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ItemsToProcess As Outlook.Items
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim sFilter As String
Dim dailyStats As CRBHA_Stats
Dim kvPairs As Collection
Dim Item As KeyValuePair
Dim today As Date
today = Date

On Error GoTo LocalErr

'set outlook objects
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Filter or only MailItems received today
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= " & AddQuotes(Format(Date, "ddddd"))
Set ItemsToProcess = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(sFilter)
Set StatsCollection = New Collection

For Each oitem In ItemsToProcess
 If CheckSubject(oitem.Subject) Then
   Set kvPairs = GetKeyValuePairs(oitem.body)
   'Iterate over the Collection and load up
   'an instance of CRBHA_Stats object
   Set dailyStats = New CRBHA_Stats
   dailyStats.SubmissionDate = today
   For Each Item In kvPairs
     If LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("EmployeeID") Then
        dailyStats.EmployeeID = Item.Value
     ElseIf LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("Approved") Then
        dailyStats.Approved = Item.Value
     ElseIf LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("Declined") Then
        dailyStats.Declined = Item.Value
     ElseIf LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("PFA") Then
        dailyStats.PFAs = Item.Value
     ElseIf LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("Followups") Then
        dailyStats.FollowUps = Item.Value
     ElseIf LCase(Item.Key) = LCase("CRA") Then
        dailyStats.CRAs = Item.Value
     End If
    Next Item

    'Add each CRBHA_Stats object to the StatsCollection
    StatsCollection.Add dailyStats

    Debug.Print dailyStats.ToString
    Debug.Print "_____________" & vbCrLf
  End If
Next oitem   '<<<<This is where it cuts out

ExitProc:
Set olapp = Nothing
Set olappns = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set ItemsToProcess = Nothing
Set dailyStats = Nothing
Exit Sub

LocalErr:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
       & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
   MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
   End If
   'Resume Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Not everything in `ItemsToProcess` is necessarily going to be a `MailItem` - could be a calendar invite for example. You need to check the type of each item before processing it.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the 'locals' window in VBA and browse the  `ItemsToProcess` variable and see if there is anything different about the second item. To me, Type mismatch implies that it's not returning a `Outlook.MailItem`. You could also try `Dim oitem As Object` and see if that will get it past the type mismatch error, and allow you to inspect the oitem object. It's not a fix, just an aid to debugging.

Answer (score 8):

```
Dim oitem As Object   'not Outlook.MailItem
'....
For Each oitem In ItemsToProcess
    if typename(oitem)="MailItem" then
        'process the mail
        '....
    end if
Next oitem
'........
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that the first two MailItems were created using Outlook, but the third MailItem was originally generated from my GMail account.  Does that make a difference?  Is Microsoft being proprietary again here, only recognizing emails generated by Outlook?  I'll try the "Dim oitem as Object" declaration and the typename(...) later today and let you know how that worked out.

Comment: Well I tried out your suggestions and they all worked.  Thanks guys.

Comment: I would suggest using the strongly typed `If TypeOf oitem Is Outlook.MailItem` instead.